# ListView SimpleCursorAdapter Updated Asynchronously

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask, simplecursoradapter

I have a class that has a SimpleCursorAdapter as a field. That adapter is used feed a listview that has a a viewBinder.

I have an asynchronous task that runs that adds an entry to the database and then updates the cursor.

In testing, if I click too quickly on the button that runs the async process, I get an error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: database [path_to_my_db] already closed
```

The code WORKS perfectly - unless... the user clicks the save button rapidly in succession... I'm new to all of this, so any input would be greatly appreciated!

Here is a stripped down version of what I'm trying to do:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private DatabaseConnector connector; // this is my class for managing SQLite
    private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter; 

    ....

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        ...

        myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.my_list_view);
        String[] = new String{"This", "part", "is", "working"};
        int[] to = new int[] {1,2,3,4}; // again, this is working...

        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.my_list_item_row, null, from, to);
        adapter.setViewBinder(new ViewBinder(){
            ... // this is all working
            ... // the viewBinder is for custom date formatting... again, all works
        });

        myListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, ExerciseInstanceViewModel>{

        MyViewModel vm; // this viewModel has a cursor member...

        public MyAsyncTask([variables-all-working]){

        }

        @Override
        protected MyViewModel doInBackground(Context... params) {

            connector = new DatabaseConnector(MyActivity.this);
            connector.open(); // TODO: Getting 'did not close database error here...'

            vm = connector.runMethodThatIncludesCursorInReturnType([input-paramters-working]);

            return vm;

            }

        // use the cursor returned from the doInBackground method 
        @Override 
        protected void onPostExecute(MyViewModel result){

            super.onPostExecute(result);

            // set instance fields in outer class...;
            // set textView, progressBar, etc..

            if (result.MyCursor != null)
            {
                adapter.changeCursor(result.MyCursor);
            }

            connector.close(); // aren't i closing the db here??? 
                        [Code to reload page with next detail items]
        }

    } 
}
```

Comment: Why don't you simply make the Save button unclickable in onPreExecute() and make it clickable again in onPostExecute()

Comment: Hi midoalageb - Great question, and I obviously wasn't clear enough in my original post. The button is titled 'Save & Next. After the data is saved, the view reloads with the next record in the list. It's like stepping through a list of customers and their orders. When the page reloads, the save&next button is clickable.

Comment: Try using Synchronized statement to prevent multiple threads accessing the same variable at the same time

Answer (score 0):

if (result.MyCursor != null)
        {
            adapter.changeCursor(result.MyCursor);
        }

```
}
```

}

connector.close();
}

try this.

Comment: Hi Rashmi - are you suggesting that I move the connector.close() **outside** of the `onPostExecute()` method?

Comment: yes..if that does not work either then the best approach for DB open close matter is using a try, catch and finally block. You are sure that finally block is executed so put connector.close() in finally block. Your issue will be resolved

Comment: Hi again, Rashmi - neither suggestion worked. I am going to try some things from this post http://www.touchlab.co/blog/single-sqlite-connection/ from @Kevin Galligan and I will update the status.

Answer (score 0):

Make a wrapper around the connector, synchronized and as a singleton. I believe you are accessing the database at the same time. This is a stripped version of one of my own:

(I am overriding the getWriteable database to enable foreign keys but you dont have too do that)

```
     public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myDatabase";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private Context context = null;
    private static DatabaseHelper instance = null;

    public static synchronized DatabaseHelper getInstance(Context context){

        if (instance == null){
            instance = new DatabaseHelper(context, null);           
        }

        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized SQLiteDatabase getWritableDatabase() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = super.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");
        return db;
    }

    private DatabaseHelper(Context context, CursorFactory factory) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
    }


}
```